# TypeError: string indices must be integers | discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, discord.py

Although the index can be a string, because it is a dictionary, it still shows the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. You can use strings as indices in a dictionary, right?

```py
File "main.py", line 63, in get_welcomechannel
    channel_id = data['welcomechannels'[str(message.guild.id)]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The function on `line 63`:

```py
def get_welcomechannel(client, message):
    with open("./data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(type(data['welcomechannels']))
        channel_id = data['welcomechannels'[str(message.guild.id)]]
    return channel_id
```

JSON file:

```json
{
    "welcomechannels": {
    "957987330889756712":"957987337516777546",
    "889211880940384287":"889211881921867866"
    }
}
```

Check if dictionary:

```py
print(type(data['welcomechannels']))
>>> <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: The problem might be your syntax. Try changing this "channel_id = data['welcomechannels'[str(message.guild.id)]]" to "channel_id = data['welcomechannels'][str(message.guild.id)]"

Comment: Now, I get another error. Apparently, the channel is none, but the channel_id is right: `channel = guild.get_channel(get_welcomechannel(client, member))`. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Share the get_channel function and I might be able to help.

Comment: That is an inbuilt function in discord.py: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel . The channel with that id exists and as I wrote earlier the `channel_id` is the right one.

Comment: So according to the documenation, get_channel takes an integer parameter. So cast the channel_id to int. Your line should be: ```channel = guild.get_channel(int(get_welcomechannel(client, member)))```

Comment: Thanks. I thought `channel_id` was already an `int`.